# Why is piping into cat faster than not piping to cat?

Tags: bash, performance, pipe, sh, cat

I've just found out that doing `find .` is slower than doing `find . | cat`. Here's the results of doing `time find .` 3 times in my home directory:

```
First:
real    0m4.385s
user    0m0.546s
sys     0m2.072s

Second:
real    0m4.090s
user    0m0.514s
sys     0m1.798s

Third:
real    0m4.197s
user    0m0.508s
sys     0m1.905s
```

Doing `time find . | cat` instead significantly improves the results:

```
First:
real    0m2.988s
user    0m0.378s
sys     0m1.649s

Second:
real    0m2.768s
user    0m0.370s
sys     0m1.471s

Third:
real    0m2.768s
user    0m0.370s
sys     0m1.471s
```

As you can tell, `find . | cat` is much faster. I'm really confused by this, the only thing `cat` does is copy its input to its output, right? I really have no idea why this is happening and I would be happy if anyone could tell me why it is.

For the record, here's the output of `find . | wc`:

```
 246646  477986 25198490
```

Thanks.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: No. In bash, `time` takes *pipeline* as argument, not a signle command.

Comment: @choroba my bad, didn't know it's a shell builtin

Comment: How are you actually doing the time tests?  I wonder if caching might have something to do with it.  For me, I have  found that the first time I do `find .` is the slowest regardless of whether or not I pipe it through `cat`.  The second incantation, and subsequent (probably until the cache misses) is faster

Answer (score 3):

The call to `find .` is not in and of itself slower than `find . | cat`. It is only slower when you are printing the output to stdout. 
When you redirect the output to `/dev/null` (specifically, calling `find . > /dev/null` and `find . | cat > /dev/null`), then you should observe that with the `| cat` is slower than without.

The only conclusion that comes to my mind from those results is that, by having cat running a separate process for printing, the `find` command is not held up by blocking prints to `stdout`, whereas the `cat` runs as a separate process and so when it is held up printing to `stdout`, the find command is still running actually finding the files.